# Prediction intervals for levels using a VAR model in second differences

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, vector-autoregression, prediction-interval

Given a VAR model for the second differences of a vector time series, $\Delta^2 y$, how to obtain the one-step-ahead (and possibly $h$-step-ahead) prediction intervals for the series in levels, $y$?

Any suggestion or resources regarding how to implement this, e.g. in R, would also be appreciated.

Comment: Have you at least started solving this problem? If you got stuck on the way, and you showed us where you got stuck, maybe we could be able to help you. I know this kind of comment may be more common for `self-study` questions, but since there was no answer in five days, perhaps you could do the first step by yourself and this way hopefully encourage potential answers.